# Make tr width match thead width on sticky table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sticky table header that I am working on. Right now, the user scrolls passed the header, and the header sticks correctly. The problem I am having is that `tableHeaderRow` is not the same width as `tableHeader`.

**Current steps for sticky header:**

1. Ajax call to fill table with data
2. Save column widths
3. Make `tableHeader` `position:absolute`
4. Set column widths back into `tableHeader` (this is where it gets *close* but about 100 pixels short)

**Tried**

1. Set `tableHeaderRow` to the expected width.
2. Set `tableHeaderRow` to `100%` width.
3. Remove `padding` and `margin`

**HTML**

```
                    <table id="table" class="table  tablesorter table-responsive table-striped table-hover" style="overflow:auto;border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <thead id='tableHeader' style="background-color:LightBlue;">
                        <tr id='tableHeaderRow' >
                            <th id="col1" class='header'>Column1</th>
                            <th id="col2" class='header'>Column2</th>
                            <th id="col3" class='header'>Column3</th>
                            <th id="col4" class='header'>Column4</th>
                            <th id="col5" class='header'>Column5</th>
                            <th id="col6" class='header'>Column6</th>
                            <th id="col7" class='header'>Column7</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                        <tbody id='tableBody'>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

**Save off widths**

```
         col1Width = $('#col1').width(); 
         col2Width = $('#col2').width();
         col3Width = $('#col3').width();
         col4Width = $('#col4').width();
         col5Width = $('#col5').width();
         col6Width = $('#col6').width();
         col7Width = $('#col7').width();
```

**Stick Scroll Event Listener**

```
    var tableHeaderTop = $("#tableHeader").offset().top;
    var above = true;

    //Window scroll event listener to fix table headers
    $( window ).scroll(function() {
        if(tableHeaderTop - $(window).scrollTop() <= 0){
         if(above){
            $('#tableHeader').css({
                position:'absolute',
                top: $(window).scrollTop() - $("#top").height() -15,
                width:$('table#table').width(),
            });


            $('.column1Value').width(col1Width);
            $('#col1').width(col1Width);

            $('.column2Value').width(col2Width);
            $('#col2').width(col2Width);

            $('.column3Value').width(col3Width);
            $('#col3').width(col3Width);

            $('.column4Value').width(col4Width);
            $('#col4').width(col4Width);

            $('.column5Value').width(col5Width);
            $('#col5').width(col5Width);

            $('.column6Value').width(col6Width);
            $('#col6').width(col6Width);

            $('.column7Value').width(col7Width);
            $('#col7').width(col7Width);

          above = false;
         }else{
            $('#tableHeader').css({
                top: $(window).scrollTop() - $("#top").height() -15,
            });

         }


        }else{
            $('#tableHeader').css({
                position:'static',
            });
          above = true;
        }
    });
```

Please ask for any clarification. Working on a bootply to show issue.

Note: I made a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/sbq41H9VTL) for the issue, but it works as I would want it to on bootply. This leads me to believe it would be some sort of 3rd party plugin that changes CSS. I will update with an answer when I have one, in the mean time if anyone wants to use my custom sticky table header code (thanks to others who helped) you're welcome to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this may not completely answer your question.
But, for what you're trying to do - this jQuery plugin is pretty much the best I've seen out there: http://www.fixedheadertable.com/

Doing a google search I also found a pure css solution (that I have no personal experience with, but if it works as intended that's just cool!): http://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/

I did a script like that myself once too.
A simplified version of it was looking something like this.
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L0oy2L01/

**HTML** (sorry for inline css styling... feel free to add your own classes!)

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr style="background-color: #ccc;">
            <td data-col="1" class="header">
                Column1
            </td>
            <td data-col="2" class="header">
                Column2
            </td>
            <td data-col="3" class="header">
                Column3
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="contentDiv" style="max-height: 50px; overflow-y: auto;">
    <table class="contentTable">
        <tr>
            <td data-col="1" class="content">
                My Content1
            </td>
            <td data-col="2" class="content">
                My Content2
            </td>
            <td data-col="3" class="content">
                My Content3
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-col="1" class="content">
                My Content4
            </td>
            <td data-col="2" class="content">
                My Content5
            </td>
            <td data-col="3" class="content">
                My Content6
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-col="1" class="content">
                My Content7
            </td>
            <td data-col="2" class="content">
                My Content8
            </td>
            <td data-col="3" class="content">
                My content9
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var totalWidth = 0;
    $('.header').each(function(){
        var colwidth = $(this).outerWidth();
        var colnumber = $(this).data('col');

            $('.content[data-col="'+ colnumber +'"]').each(function(){
                if($(this).outerWidth() >= colwidth){
                    colwidth = $(this).outerWidth();
                    }
                });

            $('td[data-col="'+ colnumber +'"]').css('width',colwidth);
            totalWidth += colwidth;
        });

    //if table height is bigger than contentDiv height there will be a scroll.. therefor we adjust contentDiv to it's content + scrolling
    if($('.contentTable').outerHeight() > 50){
        $('#contentDiv').outerWidth(totalWidth + 30);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Looking through your answers now, I will post again if I have questions. Thank you for responding. +1, I am extremely close. I believe my problem was the `<th>`'s rather than the row itself!